# What is the best book for coordinate geometry?

Tags: geometry, reference-request, soft-question, analytic-geometry, book-recommendation

Requirements:

- A) not too thick, as I am reading this only to solve calculus problem.
- B) free on web is the best (optional)
- C) I don't mind if the book involves both coordinate geometry and analytical geometry.

Any suggestion? Thanks

Answer (score 3):

Coordinate geometry by S.L Loney. Its not too thick and only includes what you need.

Answer (score 1):

I will recommend [Precalculus Mathematics in a Nutshell: Geometry, Algebra, Trigonometry
by George F. Simmons](http://www.goodreads.com/book/show/507583.Precalculus_Mathematics_in_a_Nutshell). It has coordinate geometry as well.

Answer (score 0):

Plane coordinate geometry and conic sections by Isaac Todhunter